# Converting a blank string to a NULL date

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I convert a `VARCHAR2` that contains a number of spaces into a `DATE` that is `NULL`

Comment: First, I'm not sure what your question is.  If your flat file is fixed length, my guess is that `NULL` is represented by an appropriate number of spaces.  Second, why would you use `UTL_FILE` to load data from a flat file into a table when SQL*Loader and/or external tables are specifically designed to do just that.

Comment: Hi Justin,Thanks for ur response.1. we should not use SQL Loader.And the the column value is NULL.but when i run the procedure to load it throrows Error: other error ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.

Comment: Why can't you use the proper tool?  What is the business requirement that writing a ton of `UTL_FILE` code solves that couldn't be solved much more simply with an external table?  If you're trying to debug an error, we're going to need to see the code.  My wild guess is that you are trying to convert a series of spaces from a flat file into a `DATE` or a `NUMBER` and the `to_date` or `to_number` is specifying a format mask that is incompatible with a series of spaces.

Comment: Yes.Justin im trying to convert "null" to "to_date".What is the either way to handle this problem

Comment: What are you really reading from the file?  Is a `NULL` represented as a set of spaces?  What is the actual code that you are using?  What results do you want?

Comment: Iam using PLSQL.I need to insert Null if there is no value(timestamp) in the file.Null Should be inserted in the Table

Comment: What does it mean to you to have "no value" in a fixed width file?  My assumption would be that a `NULL` would be represented as a set of spaces.  I've asked you multiple times whether that assumption/ guess is correct.  What is the actual code that you are using?

Comment: Yes Ur Assumption is right..I need to insert null whenever there is no value is found in that position

Comment: So, does your problem boil down to "How can I convert a `VARCHAR2` that contains a number of spaces into a `DATE` that is `NULL`"?

Answer (score 3):

Simply `TRIM` the string before passing it to `TO_DATE`

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_my_string varchar2(10) := '          ';
  3    l_my_date   date;
  4  begin
  5    l_my_date := to_date( trim( l_my_string ),
  6                          'mm/dd/yyyy' );
  7    if( l_my_date is null )
  8    then
  9      dbms_output.put_line( 'Yup, the date is NULL' );
 10    end if;
 11  end;
 12  /
Yup, the date is NULL

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```